# Tomcat JSP include of UTF-8 .html file not working

Tags: jsp, tomcat, utf-8

A simple UTF-8 problem with a new Tomcat running in Eclipse:
My `index.html` in UTF-8 works perfectly, and Eclipse can display the UTF characters. But wrapping it in this `index.jsp` is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  %>
<% response.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
    response.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
%>
<%@ include file="index.html" %>
```

Another JSP page without `<%@ include ...%>` has UTF-8 in the html body, and works perfectly. (It is actually on a second Tomcat instance, and managed to send "↑" across a websocket to be displayed correctly on the index.jsp via JavaScript. Only the HTML-embedded UTF in the static index.html does not render when wrapped into the index.jsp as above.)

**Why?** (If you don't know an immediate short answer, don't bother. This is too ridiculous.)

I have tried `org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter` in `web.xml`, and set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in the connector tag in `server.xml`. No effect. It gets worse when adding a `<jsp-config><jsp-property-group><page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>...` to `web.xml`: Server then complains about my Javascript files (whose UTF-8 works perfectly in static index.html)

Comment: Why did you try to wrap an existing template? Copy the content to the resulting JSP and set UTF-8 encoding with the page directive.

Comment: I'm a strict adherent of the KISS engineering principle, and simply wanted to add these two headers in a natural and flexible manner to an otherwise static html file. -- By chance this is a simplest possible nontrivial first-principles test, which JSP seems to fail in the ridicu-lousiest manner imaginable to me. But likely I'm just stupid. That's WHY I am asking :-)

Comment: (COOP and COEP HTTP headers allow JavaScript precision timer. That's all I wanted, and not bother with a few UTF-8 symbols that make my page prettier. I might as well revert to ASCII stone age.)

Comment: So I translated it into HTML-entities, instead of going full ASCII :-)  But still: Why?

Comment: Why do you need ASCII?  The character encoding depends of the capabilities of the terminal to decide that characters. Using static import with not preserving the character encoding depends of the default encoding settled by the jvm. If you not requested the encoding from the input stream then the defaults are applied as soon as i18n encoding is not specified. You have included html but it is not formatted properly neither encoded, so the pretty formattetis the best case from my point of view.